Export attribute table to Excel without vertex-points
When exporting an attribute table the amount of vertex points (correct?) sometimes makes multiple rows in Excel. Is there a simple way to stop that?


Are you asking how to stop Excel from creating multiple rows, or are you asking how to export data w/o the vertices?

See if Settings - Options - Copy features as is set to Plain text, No geometry.

Is there a way to stop Excel from creating multiple rows? If so that would be perfect. Johns suggestion is solving the problem but I must remember to change it back when working with copy/past within QGIS
